# How do i convert and calculate a string expression into arithmetic expression without external crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How do i convert and calculate a string expression into arithmetic expression without external crate
for example:  “500+10-66*32”.  expected result = 14208 (Do not want the precedence of operator)

```
//a = ‘+’, b = ‘-’, c = ‘*’, d = ‘/’, e = ‘(’, f = ‘)’
use std::collections::VecDeque;
fn calculate(s: String) -> i32 {
    let mut multi_active = false;
    const SPACE: char = ' ';
    const SIGN_PLUS: char = '+';
    const SIGN_MINUS: char = '-';
    const SIGN_MULTIPLY: char = '*';
    const SIGN_DIVIDE: char = '/';
    const PAREN_OPEN: char = '(';
    const PAREN_CLOSED: char = ')';
    let len_s: usize = s.len();
    let mut num: i32 = 0;
    let mut ans: i32 = 0;
    let mut sign: i32 = 1;
    let mut stk: VecDeque<i32> = VecDeque::with_capacity(len_s);
    stk.push_back(sign);
    for ch in s.chars() {
      println!("chars:{}",ch);
        match ch {
            '0'.. => {
                num = num * 10 + (ch as i32 - '0' as i32);
                println!("given numbers:{num}");
            }
            SIGN_PLUS | SIGN_MINUS => {
                // println!("b4 ans = {ans}");
                // println!("b4 sig = {sign}");
                // println!("b4 num = {num}");

                ans += sign * num;
                sign = stk.back().unwrap() * if ch == SIGN_PLUS { 1 } else { -1 };
                num = 0;
                // println!("addition ans  = {ans}");
                // println!("multiply sig = {sign}");
                // println!("multiply num = {num}");
                multi_active = false;

            }
            PAREN_OPEN => {
                stk.push_back(sign);
                // println!("brak open");
                // multi_active = false;

            }
            PAREN_CLOSED => {
                stk.pop_back();
                // multi_active = false;

            }
            SIGN_MULTIPLY => {
                 println!("b4 ans = {ans}"); //0  always
                 println!("b4 sig = {sign}"); // 1 always
                 println!("b4 num = {num}");// 10 first number
              // 10 = 0 + 1 * 10
           
                  ans = ans + sign * num; // current ans = 10 target=>27
                println!("simple multi- {}", ans);
                //ans=3;
                sign = stk.back().unwrap() * if ch == SIGN_MULTIPLY { 1 } else { -1 };
                num = 0;
                // println!("multiply ans = {ans}");
                // println!("multiply sig = {sign}");
                // println!("multiply num = {num}");
              multi_active = true;
              
              
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
    println!("final:{ans}@@@@{sign}@@@@{num}===={:?}",multi_active);
    // if multi_active {
    //    // ans = (ans-3)*num+ 3;
    //   ans= ans*num;

    // }
    
    // else{
      ans = ans + sign * num;
    //}

    ans
}

fn main() {
    let inputs = "2+44+6+1".to_owned();
    let outs = calculate(inputs);
    println!("{outs}");
}
```

```
Expected Results


Input: “500+10-66*32”
Result: 14208
```

I have sucessfully implementde addition and subtraction, now stuck with order of precedence from left to right.

Comment: Rust is a compiled language, not an interpreter. There is no `eval()` function that could return the value of an expression described in a string, as in Python or JS. You have to write your own interpreter in your Rust program if you want that, but this is not straightforward. A very simple arithmetic language could rely on [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

Comment: Putting aside the issue of Rust not having any way to evaluate such expressions out of the box, I'm not sure how you get 14208 from 500+10-6632.

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the question..

Comment: You question is not specific enough: as written it says do my homework for me. If we were to do that then you would not learn.

Comment: You showed the expected result. What result did you get?

Comment: I am confused, why do you want the input to be `a` instead of `+`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a poor man's calculator. No negative values, no operator precedence, no parentheticals, and no graceful error handling; use at your own risk:

```
fn main() {
    let e = "500+10-66*32";
    
    let ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
    let values: Vec<f64> = e.split(&ops).map(|v| v.trim().parse().unwrap()).collect();
    let operands: Vec<_> = e.matches(&ops).collect();
    
    let (&(mut curr), values) = values.split_first().unwrap();
    for (op, &value) in operands.into_iter().zip(values) {
        match op {
            "+" => { curr = curr + value },
            "-" => { curr = curr - value },
            "*" => { curr = curr * value },
            "/" => { curr = curr / value },
            _ => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
    
    println!("{}", curr);
}
```

```
14208
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from a few compiles errors (empty char `''`). You have no code to do the arithmetic. You are doing lexical manipulations.

I would give more advice but am stopped by confusion. I don't know what you are trying to do with the `a`s and `b`s, etc.